# GPRS PPP connect failture during LCP negotiation

Tags: gprs, ppp

I did some work to transplant TCP/IP stack to MCU. Through GPRS, MCU can connect internet.
However, I met with some trouble during LCP negotiation.The following is my solution referring networking material

1. In order to make MCU PPP simpler.The LCP option request will be respond with rejection.

   ```
   Server:7e ff 03 c0 21 01 01 00 14 02 06 00 00 00 00 05 06 b0 70 9c c3 07 02 08 02 54 06 7e

   MCU:7e ff 03 c0 21 04 01 00 04 02 06 00 00 00 00 05 06 b0 70 9c c3 07 02 08 02 69 78 7e
   ```
2. A authentication request is expected in the second step. But i get a none LCP option request.

   ```
   Server:7e ff 03 c0 21 01 02 00 04 b5 5a 7e
   ```

This means server forces MCU to start LCP negotiation.I am missing.

I send a authentication option request to server so that forcing server to start authentication option negotiation.Server respond me two packets.One is a ACK packet for authentication request.The another still is the none LCP option.

```
MCU:7e ff 03 c0 21 01 05 00 08 03 04 C0 23 ac 56 7e

Server:7e ff 03 c0 21 02 05 00 08 03 04 C0 23 bd 34 7e
Server:7e ff 03 c0 21 01 02 00 04 b5 5a 7e
```

After several "none option" request, The negotiation over. What should I do? I am l

(My english is not good .I hope you can understand my means.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you respond with Configure-Reject when modem sends Configure-Request. Then modem will send a new modified Configure-Request. See [RFC1661](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1661.html#page-26) chapter 6.4.

So you should respond with Configure-Ack when Configure-Request contains suitable values for you. So you should send Configure-Ack after the second Configure-Request.